# Looking for information pspicture/graphs with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pstricks

I draw a graph in one of my files as so:

```
...
\usepackage{pstricks} % I assume relevant
\usepackage{graphs} %Definitely relevant
\usepackage{pifont, marvosym,amssymb,mathrsfs, manfnt, amsfonts, yhmath, moreverb, pseudocode,stmaryrd }
\usepackage[tiling]{pst-fill}      % PSTricks package for filling/tiling
\usepackage{pst-text}              % PSTricks package for character path
\usepackage{pst-grad}              % PSTricks package for gradient filling
...
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,.25)
\rput(2,0){\begin{graph}(1,1) \roundnode{A}(-1,1)
\roundnode{B}(1,1)\roundnode{C}(1,-1)\roundnode{D}(-1,-1)
\edge{A}{B}\edge{B}{C}\edge{C}{D}\edge{D}{A}\autonodetext{A}[w]{01}
\autonodetext{B}[e]{11}\autonodetext{C}[e]{10}\autonodetext{D}[w]{00}
\end{graph}
} 
\rput(1.5,-1.95){$\mathbf{Q_2}$} 
\end{pspicture}
```

Since this is part of a 400 page book separated into dozens of files, I can't include all of the details, but I am hoping I included the relevant ones.

This worked fine when I compiled with latex, dvips, and ps2pdf. But I have switched to using XeLaTeX so I could get forms to work with hyperref (one of those 3 steps didn't like my TextFields). Everything compiles, but in all of the drawing done with graph/pspicture (most have a graph in a pspicture as above, but some just have a graph) the lines are missing (the values at the nodes are printed, however). This is code written by someone else (taken from an open source book) so I don't know it at all, and I haven't really ever used pspicture/graph before. I am hoping to avoid having to redraw all of the pictures using tikz or something else.

Any ideas as to why the lines won't draw when compiled with XeLaTeX? Since this is my first attempt at using XeLaTeX, I am not certain of all of the subtle differences.

Comment: Hi, welcome! It is a known issue, at least I have the same experience: compile the same PSTricks code with either `latex->drips->pdf` or `XeLaTeX`, and get different results. One does not need large documents to have this effect. Unfortunately I am not aware of a solution (but of course I cannot exclude that a solution exists). This was one of the reasons why I switched to Ti*k*Z some years back, even though I have thousands (literally) PSTricks pictures on my hard drive.

Comment: Where can the `graphs` package be found? Never heard of it.

Comment: You could add for instance this code to your question: `\documentclass[pstricks,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5.5,-2.5)(5,3.5)
 \psset{viewpoint=1 1.5 0.5}
 \ThreeDput(0,0,0){\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a.eps}}
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}`. It already shows the symptoms that the result is very different for the two compilation chains. Otherwise you may get more comments of the form that something in your code is not clear.

Comment: @Bernard I can't find any information about graphs anywhere. I googled "\usepackage{graphs}" and got 0 hits, which is really weird.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat So it sounds like I may have to redo all of the drawing in tikz or something else. That's a bummer. So far I have found the syntax of TikZ to be very confusing and convoluted (To be fair, I have never read any instructions on TikZ--I look at examples that are close to what I want to do and start there. Perhaps some day I will actually learn how it works.)

Comment: You can still compile them as standalone to postscript with a compilation chain that produces the expected result, and include the results in your document, can't you? I did that for a while but eventually I converted the vast majority of my pictures to Ti*k*Z over the time. (And yes, in the very beginning I found the syntax of Ti*k*Z confusing but this very quickly changed. Now I cannot imagine working with all the macros any more, styles are so much better. Typically when converting PSTricks to Ti*k*Z the code shrinks by a factor 2-3 and is so much easier to maintain.)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that something is different in the two processes of compiling (latex-->dvips-->ps2pdf versus XeLaTeX) that makes it so that PSTricks that work for the former do not always work for the latter. The solutions seem to be don't use XeLaTeX for such files or redraw them using TikZ, for instance.